How to transform polars expression into ColumnNameOrSelector | Sequence[ColumnNameOrSelector]
According to the documentation for polars.LazyFrame.unpivot, the on or index argument should be of type
ColumnNameOrSelector | Sequence[ColumnNameOrSelector] | None.
Apperently, it is possible to submit a pl.Expr. For instance, I could pass something like pl.all().exclude("col_1", "col_2") and it will work as expected.
However, mypy will correctly complain:
Argument "index" to "unpivot" of "LazyFrame" has incompatible type "Expr"; expected "str | _selector_proxy_ | Sequence[str | _selector_proxy_] | None"  [arg-type] 

What would be the correct/intended way of transforming a
pl.Expr
into a
ColumnNameOrSelector | Sequence[ColumnNameOrSelector]?

Passing pl.exclude("col_1", "col_2") should raise an error. Selectors are different, it would be cs.exclude()

I can submit pl.all().exclude("col_1", "col_2") without an error being raised.

Strange. I get TypeError: argument 'on': 'Expr' object cannot be converted to 'PyString' (Polars 1.6)

In your previous comment you omitted pl.all(). Just to make sure we are talking about the same pl.Expr.

Yeah, pl.exclude is just shorthand for pl.all().exclude() - they are the same thing. What version of Polars are you using?

I am using v.1.5.0.

Trying 1.5; pl.__version__; pl.DataFrame({"a": [1], "b": [2]}).pivot(on=pl.all().exclude("a")) gives me '1.5.0' and TypeError: argument 'on': 'Expr' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'

@jqurious You're correct with your example. In my actual code I was using unpivot on a pl.LazyFrame. pl.LazyFrame({"a": [1], "b": [2]}).unpivot(on=pl.all().exclude("a")).collect() results in a correct pl.DataFrame. I'll limit my question to pl.LazyFrame.unpivot.

The intended way is to use Selectors not expressions. You can use pl.exclude('a').meta._as_selector() to get a selector but that's a private method so it wouldn't be intended. Is there a reason why cs.exclude("col_1", "col_2") doesn't work? If there's a compelling reason, you could ask on the issue tracker for an enhancement.

@DeanMacGregor both of your suggestions are working fine from a functional point of view. However, mypy is always complaining that these are incompatible type Expr as per my original question.

I dunno, sometimes you've just got to typing.cast or assert isinstance to make the complaints go away.

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/18676 - It seems something changed in 1.5 which caused Expr to start working for LazyFrame methods. I'm guessing this will be formalized and something will change with regards to the typing to reflect this.
